# efficient number generator for correlation studies

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pearson-correlation

My goal is to generate 7 numbers within a min and max range that correspond to a [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) of greater than 0.95. I have been successful with 3 numbers (obviously because this isn't very computationally demanding).. however for 4 numbers, the computation required seems very large (i.e. on the order of 10k iterations). 7 numbers would be almost impossible with the current code.

Current code:

```
def pearson_def(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    n = len(x)
    assert n > 0
    avg_x = average(x)
    avg_y = average(y)
    diffprod = 0
    xdiff2 = 0
    ydiff2 = 0
    for idx in range(n):
        xdiff = x[idx] - avg_x
        ydiff = y[idx] - avg_y
        diffprod += xdiff * ydiff
        xdiff2 += xdiff * xdiff
        ydiff2 += ydiff * ydiff

    return diffprod / math.sqrt(xdiff2 * ydiff2)

c1_high = 98
c1_low = 75

def corr_gen():
    container =[]
    x=0
    while True:
        c1 = c1_low
        c2 = np.random.uniform(c1_low, c1_high)
        c3 = c1_high
        container.append(c1)
        container.append(c2)
        container.append(c3)
        y = np.arange(len(container))

        if pearson_def(container,y) >0.95:
            c4 = np.random.uniform(c1_low, c1_high)
            container.append(c4)
            y = np.arange(len(container))
            if pearson_def(container,y) >0.95:
                return container
            else:
                continue
        else:
            x+=1
            print(x)
            continue

corrcheck = corr_gen()
print(corrcheck)
```

**Final objective:**

*To have 4 columns with a [linear distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) (with evenly spaced points)

*Each row corresponds to a group of items (C1,C2,C3,C4) and their sum must equal to 100.

```
       C1      C2    C3    C4   sum   range 
 1     70      10    5     1    100    ^
 2     ..                              |  
 3     ..                              |
 4     ..                              | 
 5     ..                              |
 6     ..                              |
 7     90      20    15    3           _
```

Example spread for two theoretical components:

[image]

Comment: I'm actually keen to see `pearson_def`. The correlation is computed between two series, yet one of them seems to be the numbers 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: Correlation involves two sets of numbers. In what way can you have a set of seven numbers with a certain minimum correlation?

Comment: first thing to optimize your code is to avoid calling methods from objects. Therefore, for example put your container,appending in a variable `append = container.append`. In the while-loop you wont have to call the whole reference from now on, which is faster | Edit: Same goes for your uniform- or arange-statement as well

Comment: One of the first things in programming is to avoid early optimisation. First ensure that you're calculating what you intend to calculate.

Comment: Good point @Bill Bell .. I'm fairly sure this function is the same as just plotting the 7 'generated' numbers in excel and drawing a line of best fit and generating an r^2 value?

Comment: No, it isn't. The correlation there says how well the fitted line fits the data. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: Instead of your `pearson_def`, you could use [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html).

Comment: @Reti43 ,I'm trying to generate 7 numbers that have a correlation of >0.95. I have added a visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve (image contains 10 points not 7..)

Comment: The 'correlation' is between the selected, ordered random deviates and their order within the selected sample.

Comment: It's almost as if you want random points on a line. The end points of the line are the min and max that you mentioned.

Comment: What would you say to code that gave you points exactly on the line?

Comment: I would welcome it. Though, this is part of a larger modelling effort where I have several other sets of numbers.

Comment: Have you considered adding points one at a time? If you begin with two points and generate a random x value for a third point, it shouldn't be hard to calculate the min/max y value that would maintain >.95 pearson correlation and then take a random value between the min/max. This could be repeated indefinitely.

Comment: Create a uniform distribution with support given by the line, allowing for min and max, and sample for the seven points. Inevitably, all will be within the line.

Comment: What determines the allowed range of *x* values?  Your plot shows values between 1 and 21, but your description of the problem doesn't mention anything about the bounds on *x*.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: It's in the first sentence.

Comment: *"My goal is to generate 7 numbers within a min and max range..."* The code shows bounds on the *y* values (apparently `c1_low <= y <= c1_high`, with `c1_low = 75` and `c1_high = 98`).  What determines the allowed range of the *x* values?

Comment: If he needs to sample points along a line, that line must have a slope and intercept. So, you either define the line and the min/max y range (so that the respective x range can be calculated), or the min/max for both x and y (so that the line can be defined). And when the y points are sampled, they must come with an x-coordinate as well.

Comment: All, I have updated my question with the final goal of my project. This is to demystify what I'm trying to achieve as my final goal.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand. Why is the old part of your question still in there? Why are you still talking about Pearson's correlation? Am I correct to understand that you're simply trying to generate 4 7-point datasets, each of which lies along a line? And for each of these 7 rows, the respective points from each dataset must sum up to 100? By the way, none of the rows in your example add up to 100...

Comment: Because the Pearson correlation allows me to determine the spread of data with a linear regression... of which I want to be r^2 = > 0.95 for linear or second order polynomial. That is correct. the numbers shown in rows 1 and 7 are just to illustrate the range within which the numbers should lie. I have added two plots to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

_corr = 0.95
n = 2
size = 7

corr = np.full((n, n), _corr)
np.fill_diagonal(corr, 1.)  # inplace op

# Change as you see fit; you can scale distr. later too
mu, sigma = 0., 1.
mu = np.repeat(mu, n)
sigma = np.repeat(sigma, n)

def corr2cov(corr, s):
    d = np.diag(s)
    return d.dot(corr).dot(d)

cov = corr2cov(corr, sigma)

# While we specified parameters, our draws are still psuedorandom.
# Loop till we meet the specified threshold for correl.
res = 0.
while res < _corr:
    dist = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=mu, cov=cov, size=size)
    res = np.corrcoef(dist[:, 0], dist[:, 1])[0, 1]
```

The result you're interested in is `dist`, in this case returned as a 2d array with 2 features and 7 samples each.

Walkthrough:

- Create a correlation matrix with your specified correlation.
- Specify a mean and standard deviation, ~N(0, 1) in this case, which you can scale later if wanted.
- Convert the correlation to covariance using the standard deviation.  (They are the same in this particular case).
- Draw random samples from a multivariate normal distribution.