# Algorithm for generation of number matrix with specified boundaries

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization

I am trying to generate a matrix of numbers with 7 rows and 4 columns. Each row must sum to 100 and each column must have an even spread (if permitted) between a min and max range (specified below).

Goal:

```
       C1      C2    C3    C4   sum   range 
 1     low                      100    ^
 2     ..                              |  
 3     ..                              |
 4     ..                              | 
 5     ..                              |
 6     ..                              |
 7     high                            _

c1_high = 98
c1_low = 75
c2_high = 15
c2_low = 6
c3_high = 8
c3_low = 2
c4_low = 0.05
c4_high =0.5
```

In addition to this, i need the spread of each row to be as linear as possible, though a line fitted to the data with a second order polynomial would suffice (with an r^2 value of >0.98).

I am currently trying to do this using the following sudocode:

1. generate random number between ranges for c1,c2,c3 and c4.
2. repeat this 7 times
3. check correlation between each generated c1 value and a range of numbers from 1-7. For example:

[image]

5. repeat step 3 for c2,c3 and c4.
6. Break loop when step 3 and 4 are successful

This has proven to be too burdensome in terms of the number of iterations required and as a result, the solution is never reached.

Is there a more efficient way of achieving this solution?

So far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

c1_high = 98
c1_low = 75
c2_high = 15
c2_low = 6
c3_high = 8
c3_low = 2
c4_low = 0.05
c4_high =0.5

def matrix_gen(): #generates matrix within min and max values
    container =[]
    d={}
    offset = np.linspace(0.05,1,9)
    c1= np.linspace(c1_low, c1_high, 7)
    c2= np.linspace(c2_low, c2_high, 7)
    c3= np.linspace(c3_low, c3_high, 7)
    c4= np.linspace(c4_low, c4_high, 7)

    for i in np.arange(7):
        d["row{0}".format(i)]=[item[i] for item in [c1,c2,c3,c4]]

    df =pd.DataFrame(d)
    df.loc[4,:] = df.iloc[0,:][::-1].values
    df1 = df.drop(0)
    df1.loc[5,:] = df1.sum(axis=0)
    new_name = df1.index[-1]
    df1 = df1.rename(index={new_name: 'sum'})
    return df1

m = matrix_gen()
print(m)
```

out:

```
       row0        row1        row2     row3        row4       row5  row6
1      6.00    7.500000    9.000000   10.500   12.000000  13.500000  15.0
2      2.00    3.000000    4.000000    5.000    6.000000   7.000000   8.0
3      0.05    0.125000    0.200000    0.275    0.350000   0.425000   0.5
4     98.00   94.166667   90.333333   86.500   82.666667  78.833333  75.0
sum  106.05  104.791667  103.533333  102.275  101.016667  99.758333  98.5
```

next function:

```
def shuf():  # attempts at shuffling the values around such that the 'sum' row is as close to 100 as possible. 
    df = matrix_gen()
    df1 = df[1:4]
    count =0
    while True:
        df1 = shuffle(df1)
        df1.loc[5,:] = df1.sum(axis=0)
        for i in df1.loc[5].values:
            if 98<= i <=100:
                print('solution')
                return df1
            else:
                count+=1
                print(count)
                continue

opt = shuf()
print(opt)
```

next function will need to apply a deviation to each number to provide a sum of each row equal to 100. Optimization should include minimizing deviations.

Comment: What if you started from the other end: generate a set of support points, equidistantly distributed within the range for each column, so that they lie on a straight line. Then you shift each point by a small random offset (small enough to satisfy the constraints. You can repeat the last step a couple of times and take the valid values with the largest offsets.

Comment: This sounds great. I'll give it a try. I may get stuck applying this so-called 'shift' in a loop.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? As it stands it seems impossible, since the `95` occurring in the first column even if paired with the smallest elements of the other columns will sum to something `>100`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer , sorry should be 94!

Comment: Then, what about using the last three in order and the first upside down? That'll get you very close already

Comment: Yes, this is what I do in excel. However, I wanted to optimize and get rid of the trial-and-error steps.

Comment: @Pavel Is this what you meant? I have updated my question. P.S. ranges are different for no particular reason.

Comment: FYI for anyone answering - the correlation aspect is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47699473/7954504).

Comment: Any matrix or some uniformly-sampled matrix?

Comment: @sascha - any matrix that satisfies the requirements specified in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers are small enough for a smart brute force approach.

I use two methods to quantify and minimize deviations from the "clean" equidistant values (`linspace(low, high, 7)`). `"abserr"` for squared difference and `"relerr"` for squared error divided by squared clean value. I also check corrcoefs in the very end but I've never seen anything below 99.8%

The following code first finds the shuffle od the *clean* values with the smallest error. This takes just a few seconds, because we use the following tricks:

- split the 4 columns into two pairs
- each pair has 7! *relative* arrangements, a mangeable number even when squared (one factor for each pair)
- compute these (7!)^2 shuffles and sum *over pairs*
- to not have to iterate over all relative shuffles between the pairs we observe that the total error is minimized if the the two sets of pair sums are arranged in opposite order this is true for `"abserr"` and `"relerr"`

In the end the values are corrected to make rows sum to 100. Here again we use the fact that the summed error is minimized when evenly spread.

The code below contains two variants a legacy one `solve` which contains a small inaccuracy when minimizing `relerr` and a corrected version `improved_solve`. They frequently find different solutions but in more than 100 random problems only one led to a very slightly smaller error with `improved_solve`.

Answers to a few examples:

OP's example:

```
                ((75, 98), (6, 15), (2, 8), (0.05, 0.5))

solve relerr                            improved_solve relerr                  
table:                                  table:                                 
76.14213 15.22843  8.12183  0.50761     76.14213 15.22843  8.12183  0.50761    
79.02431 13.53270  7.01696  0.42603     79.02431 13.53270  7.01696  0.42603    
81.83468 11.87923  5.93961  0.34648     81.83468 11.87923  5.93961  0.34648    
84.57590 10.26644  4.88878  0.26888     84.57590 10.26644  4.88878  0.26888    
87.25048  8.69285  3.86349  0.19317     87.25048  8.69285  3.86349  0.19317    
89.86083  7.15706  2.86282  0.11928     89.86083  7.15706  2.86282  0.11928    
92.40924  5.65771  1.88590  0.04715     92.40924  5.65771  1.88590  0.04715    
avgerr:                                 avgerr:                                
 0.03239                                 0.03239                               
corrcoefs:                              corrcoefs:                             
 0.99977  0.99977  0.99977  0.99977      0.99977  0.99977  0.99977  0.99977
```

An example where sorting some colums ascending some descending is not optimal:

```
                ((11, 41), (4, 34), (37, 49), (0.01, 23.99))
```

Note that the solvers find different solutions, but the error is the same.

```
solve relerr                            improved_solve relerr                  
table:                                  table:                                 
10.89217 18.81374 46.53926 23.75483     11.00037 24.00080 49.00163 15.99720    
26.00087  9.00030 49.00163 15.99720     16.00107 19.00127 45.00300 19.99467    
31.00207  4.00027 45.00300 19.99467     25.74512 13.86276 36.63729 23.75483    
16.00000 29.00000 43.00000 12.00000     35.99880  8.99970 46.99843  8.00307    
20.99860 33.99773 40.99727  4.00640     41.00000  4.00000 43.00000 12.00000    
40.99863 13.99953 36.99877  8.00307     20.99860 33.99773 40.99727  4.00640    
36.35996 24.23998 39.38996  0.01010     31.30997 29.28997 39.38996  0.01010    
avgerr:                                 avgerr:                                
 0.00529                                 0.00529                               
corrcoefs:                              corrcoefs:                             
 0.99993  0.99994  0.99876  0.99997      0.99989  0.99994  0.99877  0.99997
```

This is the problem where `improved_solve` actually beats legacy `solve`:

```
                ((36.787862883725872, 43.967159949544317),
                 (40.522239654303483, 47.625869880574164),
                 (19.760537036548321, 49.183056694462799),
                 (45.701873101046154, 48.051424087501672))

solve relerr                            improved_solve relerr                  
table:                                  table:                                 
21.36407 23.53276 28.56241 26.54076     20.25226 26.21874 27.07599 26.45301    
22.33545 24.52391 26.03695 27.10370     21.53733 26.33278 25.10656 27.02333    
23.33149 25.54022 23.44736 27.68093     22.90176 26.45386 23.01550 27.62888    
24.35314 26.58266 20.79119 28.27301     24.35314 26.58266 20.79119 28.27301    
25.40141 27.65226 18.06583 28.88050     25.90005 26.71994 18.42047 28.95953    
26.47734 28.75009 15.26854 29.50403     27.55225 26.86656 15.88840 29.69279    
27.58205 29.87728 12.39644 30.14424     29.32086 27.02351 13.17793 30.47771    
avgerr:                                 avgerr:                                
 0.39677                                 0.39630                               
corrcoefs:                              corrcoefs:                             
 0.99975  0.99975  0.99975  0.99975      0.99847  0.99847  0.99847  0.99847
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import math

N_CHUNKS = 3

def improved_solve(LH, errtype='relerr'):
    N = math.factorial(7)
    # accept anything that looks like a 2d array
    LH = np.asanyarray(LH)
    # build equidistant columns
    C = np.array([np.linspace(l, h, 7) for l, h in LH])
    # subtract offset; it's cheaper now than later
    c0, c1, c2, c3 = C - 25
    # list all permutiations of a single column
    p = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(7))))
    # split into left and right halves, compute all relative permutiations
    # and sort them by their sums of corresponding elements.
    # Left pairs in ascending, right pairs in descending order.
    L = np.sort(c0 + c1[p], axis=1)
    R = np.sort(c2 + c3[p], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
    # For each pair of permutations l in L, r in R compute the smallest
    # possible error (sum of squared deviations.)
    if errtype == 'relerr':
        err = np.empty((N, N))
        split = np.linspace(0, N, N_CHUNKS+1, dtype=int)[1:-1]
        for LCH, ECH in zip(np.split(L, split, axis=0),
                            np.split(err, split, axis=0)):
            dev = LCH[:, None] + R[None, :]
            ((dev / (100+dev))**2).sum(axis=-1, out=ECH)
        del dev
    elif errtype == 'abserr':
        err = (np.add.outer(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', L, L),
                            np.einsum('ij,ij->i', R, R))
               + np.einsum('ik, jk->ij', 2*L, R))
    else:
        raise ValueError
    # find pair of pairs with smallest error
    i = np.argmin(err.ravel())
    i1, i3 = np.unravel_index(i, (N, N))
    # recreate shuffled table
    c0, c1, c2, c3 = C        
    lidx = np.argsort(c0 + c1[p[i1]])
    ridx = np.argsort(c2 + c3[p[i3]])[::-1]
    C = np.array([c0[lidx], c1[p[i1]][lidx], c2[ridx], c3[p[i3]][ridx]])
    # correct rowsums, calculate error and corrcoef and return
    if errtype == 'relerr':
        result = C * (100.0 / C.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True))
        err = math.sqrt((((result-C)/C)**2).mean())
    else:
        result = C + (25 - C.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True))
        err = math.sqrt(((result-C)**2).mean())
    rs = np.sort(result, axis=1)
    cc = tuple(np.corrcoef(ri, range(7))[0, 1] for ri in rs)
    return dict(table=result.T, avgerr=err, corrcoefs=cc)

def solve(LH, errtype='relerr'):
    LH = np.asanyarray(LH)
    if errtype=='relerr':
        err1 = 200 / LH.sum()
        diff = np.diff(LH * err1, axis=1).ravel()
    elif errtype=='abserr':
        err1 = 25 - LH.mean()
        diff = np.diff(LH, axis=1).ravel()
    else:
        raise ValueError
    C = np.array([np.linspace(-d/2, d/2, 7) for d in diff])
    c0, c1, c2, c3 = C
    p = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(7))))
    L = np.sort(c0 + c1[p], axis=1)
    R = np.sort(c2 + c3[p], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
    err = (np.add.outer(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', L, L),
                        np.einsum('ij,ij->i', R, R))
           + np.einsum('ik, jk->ij', 2*L, R)).ravel()
    i = np.argmin(err)
    i1, i3 = np.unravel_index(i, (math.factorial(7), math.factorial(7)))
    L = np.argsort(c0 + c1[p[i1]])
    R = np.argsort(c2 + c3[p[i3]])[::-1]
    ref = [np.linspace(l, h, 7) for l, h in LH]
    if errtype=='relerr':
        c0, c1, c2, c3 = [np.linspace(l, h, 7) for l, h in LH * err1]
        C = np.array([c0[L], c1[p[i1]][L], c2[R], c3[p[i3]][R]])
        err2 = 100 / np.sum(C, axis=0)
        C *= err2
        cs = list(map(sorted, C))
        err = math.sqrt(sum((c/r-1)**2 for ci, ri in zip(cs, ref) for c, r in zip(ci, ri)) / 28)
    elif errtype=='abserr':
        c0, c1, c2, c3 = [np.linspace(l, h, 7) for l, h in LH + err1]
        C = np.array([c0[L], c1[p[i1]][L], c2[R], c3[p[i3]][R]])
        err2 = 25 - np.mean(C, axis=0)
        C += err2
        cs = list(map(sorted, C))
        err = math.sqrt(sum((c-r)**2 for ci, ri in zip(cs, ref) for c, r in zip(ci, ri)) / 28)
    else:
        raise ValueError
    cc = tuple(np.corrcoef(ci, range(7))[0, 1] for ci in cs)
    return dict(table=C.T, avgerr=err, corrcoefs=cc)

for problem in [((75, 98), (6, 15), (2, 8), (0.05, 0.5)),
                ((11, 41), (4, 34), (37, 49), (0.01, 23.99)),
                ((80, 94), (5, 14), (0.5, 5), (0.05, 0.5)),
                ((36.787862883725872, 43.967159949544317),
                 (40.522239654303483, 47.625869880574164),
                 (19.760537036548321, 49.183056694462799),
                 (45.701873101046154, 48.051424087501672))]:
    for errtype in ('relerr', 'abserr'):
        print()
        columns = []
        for solver in (solve, improved_solve):
            sol = solver(problem, errtype)
            column = [[' '.join((solver.__name__, errtype))]] + \
                     [[k + ':'] + [' '.join([f'{e:8.5f}' for e in r])
                                   for r in np.atleast_2d(v)]
                      for k, v in sol.items()]
            column = (line for block in column for line in block)
            columns.append(column)
        for l, r in zip(*columns):
            print(f"{l:39s} {r:39s}")

problems = []
for i in range(0):
    problem = np.sort(np.random.random((4, 2)), axis=1) * 50
    for errtype in ('relerr', 'abserr'):
        sol0 = solve(problem, errtype)
        sol1 = improved_solve(problem, errtype)
        if not np.allclose(sol0['table'], sol1['table']):
            print(i, end= " ")
            if np.abs((sol0['avgerr']-sol1['avgerr'])
                      /(sol0['avgerr']+sol1['avgerr']))>1e-6:
                print(problem)
                problems.append(problem)
                columns = []
                for sol, name in [(sol0, 'old '), (sol1, 'improved ')]:
                    column = [[name + errtype]] + \
                             [[k + ':'] + [' '.join([f'{e:8.5f}' for e in r])
                                           for r in np.atleast_2d(v)]
                              for k, v in sol.items()]
                    column = (line for block in column for line in block)
                    columns.append(column)
                for l, r in zip(*columns):
                    print(f"{l:39s} {r:39s}")
```

Comment: Thanks, I do like a brute force tool... however when trying to run this, I get the following error:  'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/matrix solver.py", line 30, in <module>
    sol = solve(((75, 98), (6, 15), (2, 8), (0.05, 0.5)))
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/matrix solver.py", line 14, in solve
    err = ((L[:, None, :] + R[None, :, :])**2).sum(axis=-1).ravel()
MemoryError'

Comment: Oops. How much RAM do you have? It runs no prob on my 8GB laptop. We'll probably just have to chunk it a bit to make it run on your rig.

Comment: Strange.. I also have 8GB!

Comment: Ok, I've changed the line to something that should be a bit easier on the memory. Could you give it a go?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Out of curiosity, would I be in trouble with memory again if I were to extend the number of components to say 8 instead of4?

Comment: Because of the combinatorial explosion an exhaustive search would not work with 8 columns. One would have to modify the algo to do some kind of random subsampling.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for choosing my answer. I've actually found a small bug, so I recommend you have a look at the updated post which fixes it.

Comment: I'm getting the same memory error as before with the new code.

Comment: @Joey What happens if you make `N_CHUNKS` a bit larger? `8`, say? And where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks :).. error occurs at ((dev / (100+dev))**2).sum(axis=-1, out=ECH)
MemoryError

Answer (score 3):

I think an interesting approach would be to use an optimization model.

### Ordered values

Let x(i,j) be the matrix your want to fill. Then we have:

```
sum(j, x(i,j)) = 100   ∀i
L(j) ≤ x(i,j) ≤ U(j)   ∀i,j
x(i,j) = x(i-1,j) + step(j) + deviation(i,j)
   special cases:
     x(1,j) = L(j) + deviation(1,j)
     and x(m,j) = U(j) + deviation(m,j)
step(j) ≥ 0
minimize sum((i,j), deviation(i,j)^2 )
```

This is a quadratic programming problem. It is possible to absolute deviations instead of squared ones. In that case you have an LP.

The model can be refined to minimize squared relative errors.

This is a little bit related to what is called **matrix balancing** (a statistical technique often used in economic modeling).

### Unordered values

In the above I assumed the values had to be ordered. Now I understand this is not the case. I adapted the model to handle this as follows. First an overview of the results.

The input data is:

```
----     17 PARAMETER LO  

c1 80.000,    c2  5.000,    c3  0.500,    c4  0.050


----     17 PARAMETER UP  

c1 94.000,    c2 14.000,    c3  5.000,    c4  0.500
```

**Warning**: Note that this data has been changed by the poster. My answer is using the original LO and UP values before they were changed.

The model operates in three steps:

(1) populate a perfectly organized matrix without obeying the row sum constraints. This can be done outside the model. I generated simply:

```
----     53 PARAMETER init  initial matrix

            c1          c2          c3          c4      rowsum

r1      80.000       5.000       0.500       0.050      85.550
r2      82.333       6.500       1.250       0.125      90.208
r3      84.667       8.000       2.000       0.200      94.867
r4      87.000       9.500       2.750       0.275      99.525
r5      89.333      11.000       3.500       0.350     104.183
r6      91.667      12.500       4.250       0.425     108.842
r7      94.000      14.000       5.000       0.500     113.500
```

I.e. from `lo(j)` to `up(j)` with equal steps.

(2) The second step is to permute the values within a column to achieve a solution that has a close match to the row sums. This gives:

```
----     53 VARIABLE y.L  after permutation

            c1          c2          c3          c4      rowsum

r1      94.000       5.000       0.500       0.125      99.625
r2      82.333      12.500       4.250       0.500      99.583
r3      89.333       8.000       2.000       0.200      99.533
r4      87.000       9.500       2.750       0.275      99.525
r5      84.667      11.000       3.500       0.350      99.517
r6      91.667       6.500       1.250       0.050      99.467
r7      80.000      14.000       5.000       0.425      99.425
```

This is already very close and maintains "perfect" spread.

(3) Change the values a little bit by adding a deviation such that the row sums are exactly 100. Minimize the sum of the squared relative deviations. This gives:

```
----     53 VARIABLE x.L  final values

            c1          c2          c3          c4      rowsum

r1      94.374       5.001       0.500       0.125     100.000
r2      82.747      12.503       4.250       0.500     100.000
r3      89.796       8.004       2.000       0.200     100.000
r4      87.469       9.506       2.750       0.275     100.000
r5      85.142      11.007       3.501       0.350     100.000
r6      92.189       6.510       1.251       0.050     100.000
r7      80.561      14.012       5.002       0.425     100.000


----     53 VARIABLE d.L  deviations

            c1          c2          c3          c4

r1       0.374       0.001 1.459087E-5 1.459087E-7
r2       0.414       0.003 9.542419E-5 9.542419E-7
r3       0.462       0.004 2.579521E-4 2.579521E-6
r4       0.469       0.006 4.685327E-4 4.685327E-6
r5       0.475       0.007 7.297223E-4 7.297223E-6
r6       0.522       0.010       0.001 1.123123E-5
r7       0.561       0.012       0.002 1.587126E-5
```

Steps (2) and (3) have to be inside the optimization model: they have to be executed simultaneously to achieve proven optimal solutions.

The mathematical model can look like:

[image]

The model solves within a few seconds to proven global optimality using a solver like Cplex or Gurobi.

I think this is pretty cute model (ok, that is really nerdy, I know). The permutation is modeled with a permutation matrix P (binary values). This makes the model a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) model. It can be linearized fairly easily: use **absolute values** instead of squares in the objective. After proper reformulation, we end up with a **linear MIP model**. There is lots of software available to handle this. This includes libraries and packages callable from Python.

Note: I probably should not divide by `init(i,j)` in the objective, but rather by the column means in the `init` matrix. Dividing by `y(i,j)` would be the best, but that leads to another non-linearity.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution, however converting this to Python code is way outside my skills base.

Comment: I suspect an optimization model is simpler to use than it is to design some algorithm that produces something close to optimal.

Comment: I agree with this, would you be able to make some comments next to the lines to help describe what is going on (e.g. special cases?).

Comment: Are the columns supposed to be ordered (i.e. increasing from LO(j) to HI(j))?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter as long as the numbers in each column have an evenly spaced (or as close to evenly spaced) distribution between the LO and Hi. Also, I would like to point out that, if the LO/HI of each column needs to be extended/reduced slightly then this is okay (such that the solution is realized).

Comment: OK, I added my results and my model.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I still don't know how to 'pythonize' your proposed method. The first step is pretty straightforward. However, when it comes to permuting the values around, this is where is gets tricky. There is a function called 'shuffle' from the skpearn lib that can randomly shuffle the values around. I have tried to incorporate this into a loop until the 'sum' column is between 98 and 100, though the solution is never achieved. (P.S. See updated code)

Comment: This model can be implemented in python using different solvers and modeling frameworks. Pretty much straightforward.

Comment: Eg the MIQP model can be expressed directly into the python interfaces of Cplex or Gurobi. A MIP formulation can be implemented easily in Pulp. Just to name a few.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you haven't shared the code that generates to 'results' sections of your answer?

Comment: Three reasons. I did not use python to solve this model. I think it is more important to understand the concepts than just copying code. Finally the pure math is more compact. Again, transcribing this into python is not really rocket science.

Comment: I know it's not exactly brain surgery but the transition from this level of math to code is quite a leap.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. It is appreciated. It does give me a comprehensive understanding of the solutions concept.

Comment: _I probably should not divide by init(i,j) in the objective_ - very true.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: Which programming language did you use for the above solution?